# Is it possible to bind two models to one control?

Tags: sapui5

I need to display two numbers in my StandardTile. The data source is a SOAP web service, which I had to call twice with different parameters to obtain these two numbers. Is there any way to fill the tile with these two figures? I tried creating one XMLModel per each ajax call to the web service, and then binding the property of the control to the node from the response, but I'm just getting the same figure duplicated.

Below is my onInit method in the controller

```
onInit: function () {
        // callback from ajax request
        SOAPRequester.getMessageOverview(function (data) {
            var oModel = new sap.ui.model.xml.XMLModel();
            oModel.setData(data);
            var oStandardTile = sap.ui.getCore().byId("__xmlview0--messageOverviewTile");
            if (oStandardTile !== undefined) {
                oStandardTile.setModel(oModel, "overview");
                oStandardTile.bindProperty("number", {
                    path: "/SOAP-ENV:Body/rpl:getMessageListResponse/Response/rn5:number",
                    model: "overview"
                });
            }
        });
        //callback from the second ajax call
        SOAPRequester.getErrorMessages(function (callbackData) {
            var oModel = new sap.ui.model.xml.XMLModel();
            oModel.setData(callbackData);
            var oStandardTile = sap.ui.getCore().byId("__xmlview0--messageOverviewTile");
            if (oStandardTile !== undefined) {
                oStandardTile.setModel(oModel, "overview");
                oStandardTile.bindProperty("infoState", "Error");
                oStandardTile.bindProperty("info", {
                    path: "/SOAP-ENV:Body/rpl:getMessageListResponse/Response/rn5:number",
                    model: "overview"
                });
            }
        });


    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. You are using the same model name twice, thus the firs one is not visible anymore. Simply use different model name, i.e. "overview" and "overview2" or what ever you prefer:

```
onInit: function () {
    // callback from ajax request
    SOAPRequester.getMessageOverview(function (data) {
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.xml.XMLModel();
        oModel.setData(data);
        var oStandardTile = sap.ui.getCore().byId("__xmlview0--messageOverviewTile");
        if (oStandardTile !== undefined) {
            oStandardTile.setModel(oModel, "overview");
            oStandardTile.bindProperty("number", {
                path: "/SOAP-ENV:Body/rpl:getMessageListResponse/Response/rn5:number",
                model: "overview"
            });
        }
    });
    //callback from the second ajax call
    SOAPRequester.getErrorMessages(function (callbackData) {
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.xml.XMLModel();
        oModel.setData(callbackData);
        var oStandardTile = sap.ui.getCore().byId("__xmlview0--messageOverviewTile");
        if (oStandardTile !== undefined) {
            oStandardTile.setModel(oModel, "overview2");
            oStandardTile.bindProperty("infoState", "Error");
            oStandardTile.bindProperty("info", {
                path: "/SOAP-ENV:Body/rpl:getMessageListResponse/Response/rn5:number",
                model: "overview2"
            });
        }
    });

},
```

**Hint:** You could also improve your code a little, i.e.

- call `this.getView().byId("messageOverviewTile")` or if you have the right UI5 version `this.byId("messageOverviewTile")` instead of `sap.ui.getCore().byId("__xmlview0--messageOverviewTile")`
- Do the binding for your controls in your view and then in `onInit()` call `this.getView().setModel(oModel, "overview")` and `this.getView().setModel(oModel, "overview2")`